# Is using python script to send email (from mydomain.com) different from using webmail?

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a personal domain name (let's call it domain.com) that uses publicly signed a certificate to send and receive emails. I use iRedMail webmail, and I can send emails to almost any other domain names including gmail.com and ymail.com with no issue.
Now I would want to send email using python script locally from the same email server box. here is a part of my code:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = "Welcome to my website"
msg['from'] = "activity@mydomain.com"

part = MIMEText("Body of the email",'plain')
msg.attach(part)

fromaddr = "activity@mydomain.com"
toaddrs  = "someone@gmail.com" 
username = "activity@mydomain.com"
password = "password"

# The actual mail send  
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mydomain.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    #server.ehlo()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string() )
    server.quit()
except:
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

and here is the log from /var/log/mail.log:

```
Oct 19 22:11:52 box postfix/smtp[28666]: Untrusted TLS connection established to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.198.26]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Oct 19 22:11:52 box postfix/smtp[28666]: B3F0F10583D: to=<someone@gmail.com>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.198.26]:25, delay=602, delays=598/0.01/4/0.5, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.198.26] said: 421-4.7.0 [202.89.139.221      15] Our system has detected that this message is 421-4.7.0 suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP address. 421-4.7.0 To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has 421-4.7.0 been temporarily rate limited. Please visit 421 4.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. t16si4047297oih.239 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

What am I missing here? Why is this a different behaviour?

Comment: seems like gmail has blacklisted your IP for some time, because you have done something malicious according to Gmail standard, like connecting / disconnecting at very high rate or sending too many emails in short amount of time etc ? ...

Comment: the details of error: 421:
https://www.rackaid.com/blog/gmail-blacklist-removal/

Comment: Update: I am now using mailclient explained https://github.com/aesptux/mailclient. When I use my webmail I can see the email in the mail box but when I use the python script the email goes to the junk. Anybody know the reason?